# Pinging a server says offline even if it's online?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I'm trying to see if some servers are online on a range of ports on an IP. It always says offline for some reason. I tried the pinging method in another application and it works flawlessly. This application I'm making is multithreaded but I don't know if that actually affects the pinging. Here is the main class where I'm doing it all

```
public class Tools extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField textField;

public static String ip;
public static int port;
public static int startPort;
public static int lastPort;

public static JList<String> list;
public static JList<String> list_1;
public static JList<String> list_2;

public static DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
public static DefaultListModel<String> model_1 = new DefaultListModel<>();
public static DefaultListModel<String> model_2 = new DefaultListModel<>();

public static Thread[] threads = new Thread[256];
private JButton btnStopBeforeIt;
private JTextField textField_1;
private JTextField textField_2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Tools frame = new Tools();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Tools() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 846, 694);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(20, 11, 369, 50);
    contentPane.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnStart = new JButton("Start");
    btnStart.setBounds(399, 11, 89, 50);
    contentPane.add(btnStart);

    list = new JList<String>();
    list.setBounds(552, 88, 256, 557);
    contentPane.add(list);

    list_1 = new JList<String>();
    list_1.setBounds(20, 88, 256, 557);
    contentPane.add(list_1);

    list_2 = new JList<String>();
    list_2.setBounds(286, 88, 256, 557);
    contentPane.add(list_2);

    btnStopBeforeIt = new JButton("STOP BEFORE IT CRASHES UR COMPUTER");
    btnStopBeforeIt.setForeground(Color.RED);
    btnStopBeforeIt.setBounds(498, 0, 310, 31);
    contentPane.add(btnStopBeforeIt);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(498, 42, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    textField_2 = new JTextField();
    textField_2.setBounds(722, 42, 86, 20);
    contentPane.add(textField_2);
    textField_2.setColumns(10);

    JLabel lblRanges = new JLabel("Ranges");
    lblRanges.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 16));
    lblRanges.setBounds(622, 42, 68, 19);
    contentPane.add(lblRanges);

    JLabel lblStart = new JLabel("Start");
    lblStart.setBounds(527, 63, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblStart);

    JLabel lblEnd = new JLabel("End");
    lblEnd.setBounds(757, 63, 46, 14);
    contentPane.add(lblEnd);

    btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(!textField.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("")){

                startPort = Integer.parseInt(textField_1.getText());
                lastPort = Integer.parseInt(textField_2.getText());

                port = startPort;

                ip = textField.getText();

                loadThreads();

                startThreads();

            }else{
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The IP address textbox cannot be left blank!", "Derpius Tools", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            }
        }
    });

    btnStopBeforeIt.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            stopThreads();
        }
    });

}

public static void loadThreads(){
    for(int i = 0; i != 256; i++){
        threads[i] = new Thread(new Pinger());
    }
}

public static void startThreads(){
    for(int i = 0; i != 256; i++){
        threads[i].start();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void stopThreads(){
    for(int i = 0; i != 256; i++){
        threads[i].stop();
    }
}
    }
```

Here is my Pinger class:

```
class Pinger implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run() {
    if(serverIsOnline()){
       Tools.model.addElement(Tools.ip);
       Tools.model_1.addElement("Online!");
       Tools.model_2.addElement(String.valueOf(Tools.port));
       Tools.list.setModel(Tools.model);
       Tools.list_1.setModel(Tools.model_1);
       Tools.list_2.setModel(Tools.model_2);
       System.out.println(Tools.ip + ":" + Tools.port + " is online!");
    }else{
        System.out.println(Tools.ip + ":" + Tools.port + " is not online!");
    }

    if(Tools.port != Tools.lastPort){
       Tools.port++;
    }

}

public static boolean serverIsOnline() { 
    try (Socket s = new Socket(Tools.ip, Tools.port)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
    return false;
}

 }
```

Comment: Is it possible the the ping service is not running on the server or is being blocked by fire walls or routers...

Comment: To clarify, do you see `... is online!` or `... is offline!` on stdout?

Comment: Or you might be getting an exception...a silent one

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what the actual problem is.

If it's that the thread reports that the server is online, but the GUI is showing offline, it may be because you're updating the Swing components on a non-event thread.  You should use the [SwingUtilities.invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29) to update the components.

**UPDATE**

As [boxed__l](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1572356/boxed-l) correctly pointed out, you are silently swallowing the exception in your ping method.  Printing the stack trace would give a better idea as to what is happening.

```
public static boolean serverIsOnline() { 
    try (Socket s = new Socket(Tools.ip, Tools.port)) {
        return true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        // log the exception here, at the very least:
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}
```